# (node:19640) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeConnectionError: Unknown database 'tech_blog_db'

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I am completing my assignment but have run into an error i have never encountered before.

```
(node:19640) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeConnectionError: Unknown database 'tech_blog_db'
    at ConnectionManager.connect (C:\Users\Proto Merkabah\Desktop\projects\tech-blog\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\connection-manager.js:126:17)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:19640) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:19640) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I have a schema file set up which only has two lines of code

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS tech_blog_db;

CREATE DATABASE tech_blog_db;
```

And a .env file setup as well for the mysql credentials.
I've checked to see if i have my packages installed and i have all that i need, including mysql and sequalize.

Comment: Did you read the log carefully? It says This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch() Did you check if you do these?